# htaccess RewriteCond with whitespace

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

when I use a whitespace in RewriteCond I get an Internal Server Error. So I tried with "\s", like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cid=([0-9]+)&pc=([\w\s]+)
RewriteRule ^sendungsverfolgung.html?(.*) http://www.orderrace.org/g?olist&cid=%1&pc=%2&nspace=juergensen$1
```

Result is that the URL is always cut after the whitespace. What else could I try?

Comment: try escaping the space "&pc=([\w\ ]+)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+sendungsverfolgung.html?\?cid=([^&]+)&pc=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.orderrace.org/g?olist&cid=%1&pc=%2&nspace=juergensen [R=302,L,NE]
```